# Activate text box when the user selects a value in a combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery

When a user ONLY selects Male from the following combobox, i want to display a textfield below. This should only happen when the user selects the value Male.

```
function genderfind(val) {
    var element = document.getElementById('gender');
    if (val == 'male' ) {
        element.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```html
<td align="left">
    <select id="gender" name="gender" onchange='genderfind(this.value);'>
        <option value="female">female</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

When the user selects 'male' from the above combobox, the following textbox which is inside a `<tr>` should display. In the code i tried it doesn't work. Help

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" name="gender" id="gender" style='display:none;'>Text box</td>
    <td align="left" name="gender" id="gender" style='display:none;'>
        <input id="gender_id" type="text" name="gender" style='display:none;'>
    </td>
    <td align="left" id="gender" name="gender"><span id="validate"></span>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid: the `id` attribute should be unique. You've given all your controls the same `id` (and the same `name`, which is valid for form elements but probably not really what you want to do given that it doesn't make sense to give a `name` to td elements). It seems to me it would make more sense if the tr element was `display:none`, rather than hiding the individual items in the row.

Comment: I made code changes as you suggested, but still there isn't a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
body #container .item .bg_img{background:url('search-icon-2x.png') no-repeat; height:50px;}
</style>
<script>
function genderfind(val) {
            //var element = document.getElementById('gender').value;
            //alert(element);
            if (val == 'male' ) {
                document.getElementById('genderbox').style.display = 'block';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('genderbox').style.display = 'none';
            }

        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="bg_img"></div>
        <h1>morning</h1>
        <h2>today</h2>
        <p>lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
            <select id="gender" name="gender" onchange='genderfind(this.value);'>
            <option value="female">female</option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td id="genderbox" style="display:none;">
            <input type="text" name="name" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use jQuery.

You can do a thing like that:

```
$('#gender').on('change', function(){
   var g = $(this).val();
   if(g == 'male') {
     $('#gender_id').show();
   }
   else 
   {
     $('#gender_id').hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Do  i have to make changes to my HTML. or is it the same?

Comment: Just make ids unique in the whole html page. E.g. remove id="gender" in all TDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use getElementsByName instead.

```
function genderfind(val) {
    var element = document.getElementsByName('gender');
    for(int i=0;i<element.lenght;i++)
    {          
        if (val == 'male' ) {
            element[i].style.display = 'block';
        } else {
                  element[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: There is no `getElementByName()` method. It is `getElementsByName()` (note the "s").

Comment: I'm not sure now if I misread it or if you edited it within the first five minutes before the edit history kicked in, but either way your code still won't work because `.getElementsByName()` returns a list (an HTMLCollection) of elements, not a single element, so you'll get an error when you say `element.style...`

Comment: man. one should atleast have the common sense to update the mistakes. Answer here is to guide the person to a right direction.